# Does the figurine's owner being a higher level increase the figurine's power?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, feats

If you gain an animal companion/Familiar via the feat [Companion Figurine](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/companion-figurine/), does that companion/familiar gain the normal benefit of being a higher level?

Comment: I strongly suspect that there is a confusion because the feat's wording is ambiguous; it says you may select the animal as a familiar or companion and has no explicit requirement that you actually have a relevant class feature. I'm pretty sure the intention of the feat is the choice becomes an option for a character with the right class feature but a naive reading would be that anyone at all can take the feat and get a familiar/animal companion without further qualification.

Answer (score 1):

The description of the ability says

> The figurine has the standard abilities of a familiar or animal companion of its type, plus additional abilities related to its figurine type (see below).

This indicates the creature summoned by the figurine doesn't have the stats normally associated with that creature. Instead, the stats are built as normal for an animal companion or familiar based on the owner's level, as modified by the specific figurine.

So, for example, the Ebony Fly figurine normally has the stats of a pegasus (despite being the size of a Pony i.e. Medium rather than Large). If you take an Ebony Fly as a companion, you instead create it as a horse companion, but it also gains flying when the owner hits level 8. With the Golden Lions, one of the lions would retain the normal lion stat line, but the other would be built as a Lion Animal Companion.

As has been mentioned in comments, the feat should probably have a prerequisite of being able to have an animal companion or familiar already. It does not appear that the intention was to add this capability to a character that doesn't have it, but rather modify the way it works. The feat also allows all those wannabe Drizzt-clones to finally have a statue-companion, albeit not a panther :)